# Why should one use a build system over that which is included as part of an IDE?

Tags: build, build-process

I've heard more than one person say that if your build process is clicking the build button, than your build process is broken. Frequently this is accompanied with advice to use things like `make`, `cmake`, `nmake`, `MSBuild`, etc. What exactly do these tools offer that justifies manually maintaining a separate configuration file?

EDIT: I'm most interested in answers that would apply to a single developer working on a ~20k line C++ project, but I'm interested in the general case as well.

EDIT2: It doesn't look like there's one good answer to this question, so I've gone ahead and made it CW. In response to those talking about Continuous Integration, yes, I understand completely when you have many developers on a project having CI is nice. However, that's an advantage of CI, not of maintaining separate build scripts. They are orthogonal: For example, Team Foundation Build is a CI solution that uses Visual Studio's project files as it's configuration.

Comment: MSBuild is largely what Visual Studio uses when you click the build button.

Comment: @John: Not for C/C++ projects, and not for everything.

Comment: That sounds like the programmer standard "If I can't open the hood, it can't possibly be doing what I want" comment.  You can build in continuous integration using the devenv commandline with just your .sln file.

Comment: @David: At least it's not NIH. :)

Comment: Am happy to see this question here (was just about to ask the same question). Am surprised it doesn't have more upvotes, as it's quite an important question that newbie developers should be asking themselves and understanding the importance of learning CMake or Gradle. Most people simply seem to be content using the IDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from continuous integration needs which everyone else has already addressed, you may also simply want to automate some other aspects of your build process.  Maybe it's something as simple as incrementing a version number on a production build, or running your unit tests, or resetting and verifying your test environment, or running FxCop or a custom script that automates a code review for corporate standards compliance.  A build script is just a way to automate something in addition to your simple code compile.  However, most of these sorts of things can also be accomplished via pre-compile/post-compile actions that nearly every modern IDE allows you to set up.

Truthfully, unless you have lots of developers committing to your source control system, or have lots of systems or applications relying on shared libraries and need to do CI, using a build script is probably overkill compared to simpler alternatives.  But if you are in one of those aforementioned situations, a dedicated build server that pulls from source control and does automated builds should be an essential part of your team's arsenal, and the easiest way to set one up is to use `make`, `MSBuild`, `Ant`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

One reason for using a build system that I'm surprised nobody else has mentioned is flexibility.  In the past, I also used my IDE's built-in build system to compile my code.  I ran into a big problem, however, when the IDE I was using was discontinued.  My ability to compile my code was tied to my IDE, so I was forced to re-do my entire build system.  The second time around, though, I didn't make the same mistake.  I implemented my build system via makefiles so that I could switch compilers and IDEs at will without needing to re-implement the build system yet again.

I encountered a similar problem at work.  We had an in-house utility that was built as a Visual Studio project.  It's a fairly simple utility and hasn't needed updating for years, but we recently found a rare bug that needed fixing.  To our dismay, we found out that the utility was built using a version of Visual Studio that was 5-6 versions older than what we currently have.  The new VS wouldn't read the old-version project file correctly, and we had to re-create the project from scratch.  Even though we were still using the same IDE, version differences broke our build system.

When you use a separate build system, *you* are completely in control of it.  Changing IDEs or versions of IDEs won't break anything.  If your build system is based on an open-source tool like `make`, you also don't have to worry about your build tools being discontinued or abandoned because you can always re-build them from source (plus fix bugs) if needed.  Relying on your IDE's build system introduces a single point of failure (especially on platforms like Visual Studio that also integrate the *compiler*), and in my mind that's been enough of a reason for me to separate my build system and IDE.

On a more philosophical level, I'm a firm believer that it's not a good thing to automate away something that you don't understand.  It's good to use automation to make yourself more productive, but only if you have a firm understanding of what's going on under the hood (so that you're not stuck when the automation breaks, if for no other reason).  I used my IDE's built-in build system when I first started programming because it was easy and automatic.  I later started to become more aware that I didn't really understand what was happening when I clicked the "compile" button.  I did a little reading and started to put together a simple build script from scratch, comparing my output to that of the IDE's build system.  After a while I realized that I now had the power to do all sorts of things that were difficult or impossible through the IDE.  Customizing the compiler's command-line options beyond what the IDE provided, I was able to produce a smaller, slightly faster output.  More importantly, I became a better programmer by having real knowledge of the entire development process from writing code all the way down through the generation of machine language.  Understanding and controlling the entire end-to-end process allows me to optimize and customize all of it to the needs of whatever project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have 5 people working on the same set of code.  Each of of those 5 people are making updates to the same set of files.  Now you may click the build button and you know that you're code works, but what about when you integrate it with everyone else.   The only you'll know is that if you get everyone else's and try.  This is easy every once in a while, but it quickly becomes tiresome to do this over and over again.

With a build server that does it automatically, it checks if the code compiles for everyone all the time. Everyone always knows if the something is wrong with the build, and what the problem is, and  no one has to do any work to figure it out.  Small things add up, it may take a couple of minutes to pull down the latest code and try and compile it, but doing that 10-20 times a day quickly becomes a waste of time, especially if you have multiple people doing it.  Sure you can get by without it, but it is so much easier to let an automated process do the same thing over and over again, then having a real person do it.

Here's another cool thing too.  Our process is setup to test all the sql scripts as well. Can't do that with pressing the build button.  It reloads snapshots of all the databases it needs to apply patches to and runs them to make sure that they all work, and run in the order they are supposed to.  The build server is also smart enough to run all the unit tests/automation tests and return the results.  Making sure it can compile is fine, but with an automation server, it can handle many many steps automatically that would take a person maybe an hour to do.

Taking this a step further, if you have an automated deployment process along with the build server, the deployment is automatic.  Anyone who can press a button to run the process and deploy can move code to qa or production.  This means that a programmer doesn't have to spend time doing it manually, which is error prone.  When we didn't have the process, it was always a crap shoot as to whether or not everything would be installed correctly, and generally it was a network admin or a programmer who had to do it, because they had to know how to configure IIS and move the files.  Now even our most junior qa person can refresh the server, because all they need to know is what button to push.

Comment: How does the build system fix that for you? EDIT: Nvm. So you're saying the main point is for CI stuff.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much like I did.  What was new here?

Comment: @Kevin: If you have a build system *more complicated* than clicking build, I understand completely. However, I've been told several times that even if it's as simple as clicking build than your process is broken. @duffy: I don't see anything new here. Do you? :)

Comment: The thing is that by clicking build, you have to assume that you have the most current version of the code.  If you are the only person working it that's easy, if not then you have to coordinate to get it.  With an automation server, that's not necessary, because it will be smart enough to always get the most current version of the code.  Our build server also check 4 different branches all the time to make sure that they all work, which is something that can't be done by a person very easily.

Comment: Suppose you need to get a new developer set up. Or maybe on of your boxes dies and you need to reinstall it. Or any number of other reasons you might ned to set up a new build environment. If your IDE is your build process, alot of that stuff is things that you can't check into source control, and basically have to remember. Whereas your makefile *can* be checked in and kept up to date.

Comment: @Kevin: That does seem useful for teams. In my case, however, I do not have the resources to be running a dedicated build machine. It's not a bad answer to my original question -- I just don't have use for a CI server at this point, given the project is a one man show :)

Comment: @Anon: Why can't an IDE file be checked into source control? It's just an XML file. I blow away and clone my repository on a regular basis without problems and I don't currently use a build system like this.

Comment: It depends, it may not be beneficial for you.  For us, we have different needs.  For us to build the MSIs etc., and get ready to deploy code, it takes us about 30 steps all in all.  Generate scripts, setup MSIs, build config files etc.  Can you do basic stuff by pressing build, sure, but the advanced stuff will be much harder, or not possible at all.  It all depends on what you need done.  Now that I have a build server, would I go back? No, because now that I know what I can do with it, I never want to be limited by not having one again.  The extra money spent will always be worth it to me.

Comment: Here's a way to think about it a build server on linux probably costs about what 400 bucks for hardware? So if I'm a consultant and I bill at 50 dollars an hour, that means if it saves me 8 hours of time where I can bill, it's paid for itself.  Anything after that, I'm making money, on essentially doing nothing than letting a machine sit there and do the work for me.  Now does this apply all the time, no, but I bet that eventually it will pay off.

Comment: @Billy: Just take a peek inside, say, a `.csproj` file. If you use any nonstandard libraries, either you need to specify their path in the project file, or ensure the IDE is set up correctly to find them. IDE configuration is not exactly something you can stick in source control.

Comment: @Anon: With regards to path to project file or nonstandard libraries, you have the same issues with a build script.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a hands-off, continuous integration build process it's going to be driven by an Ant or make-style script.  Your CI process will check the code out of version control when changes are detected onto a separate build machine, compile, test, package, deploy, and create a summary report.

Comment: If you need to have a CI system, then of course you'd need to configure it lol. Not a bad answer, but I'm curious if there's something not CI related here.

Answer (score 2):

the IDE build systems I've used are all usable from things like Automated Build / CI tools so there is no need to have a separate build script as such.

However on top of that build system you need to automate testing, versioning, source control tagging,  and deployment (and anything else you need to release your product).

So you create scripts that extend your IDE build and do the extras.

Answer (score 1):

One practical reason why IDE-managed build descriptions are not always ideal has to do with **version control** and the need to integrate with changes made by other developers (ie. merge).

If your IDE uses a single flat file, it can be very hard (if not impossible) to merge two project files into one. It may be using a text-based format, like XML, but XML it notoriously hard with standard diff/merge tools. Just the fact that people are using a GUI to make edits makes it more likely that you end up with unnecessary changes in the project files.

With distributed, smaller build scripts (CMake files, Makefiles, etc.), it can be easier to reconcile changes to project structure just like you would merge two source files. Some people prefer IDE project generation (using CMake, for example) for this reason, even if everyone is working with the same tools on the same platform.

Comment: Hmm.. yes but the IDE files are getting created in any case. Nobody wants to spend all day writing code without code completion features.

Comment: I know plenty of developers using text editors without code completion. In any case, my point was that IDE files don't have to be version controlled if you use an IDE-neutral build description file. You can version control that file and let developers generate the projects for their IDE of choice.